# VBA-Paste by values between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to copy a worksheet(Table1) of workbook1 to worksheet(cSrcTabName) of workbook2.

the below does not work for paste by values

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(DepFile)
wbk.Sheets("Table1").Range("A1:BF200000").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbk.Close
Set wbk = Nothing
```

Note:
cSrcTabName= constant

Worksheet(Table1) has merged columns and logos for few rows at the top. This needs otb unmerged on copying.

Help me by correcting the above code.

tnx.

Comment: Please state what your problem is or what the error is. Always end your question with a question. (and a question mark "?")

Comment: i do not see the code copied to the destination. The workbook is empty.The same code even works for me in other worksheets which do not have merged columns.

Comment: I think you mean cell contents instead of "code".

Comment: Exactly. You're right. Thats where the code fails to copy

Comment: You mentioned merged columns; try `wbk.Sheets("Table1").Range("A1:BF200000").unMerge` or `wbk.Sheets("Table1").Range("A1:BF200000").MergeArea.UnMerge`

Comment: Which cells exactly do you have merged?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put the sheet name in "", change this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

to this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cSrcTabName").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: cSrcTabName is a constant.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the source file has merged columns and few rows at the top having logos(which can be ignored). On transformation we need to unmerge or delete the blank columns.

Comment: This additional information should be edited into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub ExamplePasteSpecial()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
ws.Range("A1:G10").Copy
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

it works perfect.

Comment: No.This does not work for me. Say you have columns (I-L) in source file merged to have one cell value like a name. In this condition it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Workbook 2 has reference to directory of workbook 1. By refering the path, the wrkbook is loaded with paste special and ignoring all empty columns too.

```
Option Explicit

Sub csvFileImport()

Const cSrcTabName = "SrcSheet"  'Worksheet Name of destination workbook
Const cFileLocWS = "Master"   'Worksheet name that contains File location information
Const cFileName = "FileDirectory"   'Range name for FQDN filename
Const cTimestamp = "FileTimeStamp"   'Range name for timestamp of load process
Const cStatus = "Status"
Const cFirstVal = "Emp Name"   'First Column Heanding value


Dim vLCRWB As Workbook   'Destination Workbook
Dim vSrcWB As Workbook   'Source data workbook
Dim vSrcFileName As String   'Source data workbook FQDN filename
Dim vRowCount, vColCount, vLoopCount   'Loop counters

'
'*******************************************************************
'


'Application settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Loading source file....."



'Delete the  worksheet if exists in destination workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(cSrcTabName).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'Retrieve FQDN filename
vSrcFileName = Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cFileName).Value

'Check if file exists
If Not (Dir(vSrcFileName) > "") Then
    Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cTimestamp).Value = Now()
    Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cTimestamp).NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS"
    Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cStatus).Font.Color = vbRed
    Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cStatus).Value = "File Not Found"
    Application.StatusBar = "File Not Found!!!"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub 'Exit if file does not exists
End If



'File Exists Create Worksheet
Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = cSrcTabName  'Add worksheet to the end of the workbook



'Open source file workbook
Set vLCRWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set vSrcWB = Workbooks.Open(vSrcFileName)

If vSrcWB.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
    'More than 1 worksheet found....
    '  what to do!!!!!!!!

End If



' Select and Copy the data across from the data source file to destination workbook
'  Ref by worksheet name or number???
vSrcWB.Sheets(1).Activate

With ActiveWindow
    .ScrollRow = 1
    .ScrollColumn = 1
    Call Cells(rowIndex:=.ScrollRow, ColumnIndex:=.ScrollColumn).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    vLCRWB.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With



' Close data source workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
vSrcWB.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
vLCRWB.Activate


' Clean up formatting
' - remove blank column
' - remove blank rows
'  File Layout Assumptions :-
'  * Header Row is copied across to Repo worksheet as well
'  * "Emp Name" Column is the first cell that has data
'  * Emp Name is the first Column with Data
vRowCount = vLCRWB.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
vColCount = vLCRWB.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

'Delete blank Columns
vLoopCount = 1
Do While vLoopCount <= vColCount
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(cSrcTabName).Columns(vLoopCount)) > 0 Then
        vLoopCount = vLoopCount + 1
    Else
        Sheets(cSrcTabName).Columns(vLoopCount).Delete
        vColCount = vColCount - 1
    End If
Loop

'Delete blank Rows
vLoopCount = 1
Do While vLoopCount <= vRowCount
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(cSrcTabName).Rows(vLoopCount)) > 0 Then
        vLoopCount = vLoopCount + 1
    Else
        Sheets(cSrcTabName).Rows(vLoopCount).Delete
        vRowCount = vRowCount - 1
    End If
Loop


'Remove Rows with no Emp Name Number; Assume Column A is Emp Name after clean up
vRowCount = vLCRWB.Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

If Trim(Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(1, 1).Value) = cFirstVal Then
    vLoopCount = 1
    Do While vLoopCount <= vRowCount
        If Sheets(cSrcTabName).Cells(vLoopCount, 1).Value = "" Then
            Sheets(cSrcTabName).Rows(vLoopCount).Delete
            vRowCount = vRowCount - 1
        Else
            vLoopCount = vLoopCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
End If



'Format Output
Sheets(cSrcTabName).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
Call fSetPageLayout(cSrcTabName)


'App Settings - Complete
Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cTimestamp).Value = Now()
Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cTimestamp).NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS"
Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cStatus).Font.Color = vbGreen
Sheets(cFileLocWS).Range(cStatus).Value = "Success!"
Application.StatusBar = "source Sucessfully Imported!!!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```